# Test if controller response is defined in Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I want to test if a controller response is defined like this:

```
{% if {{ render(path('controller_url', { 'code': 'code' } )) }} is defined %}
<div>
  phone : {{ render(path('footer_params', { 'code': 'telephone' } )) }}
</div>
{% endif %}
```

But I get this error:

> Twig_Error_Syntax: A hash key must be a quoted string, a number, a name, or an expression enclosed in parentheses (unexpected token "punctuation" of value "{" in "::footer.html.twig" at line 10.

I tried to put the render between () but I still get the same error.

This is my controller:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/footer_params/{code}", name="footer_params", defaults={"code"=null})
 *
 * @Template()
 */
public function footerParamsAction($code)
{
    $sParams = $this->getWebService('get_config_param', array('code' => $code));

    if ( !isset($sParams) )
    {
        throw new AccessDeniedException();
    }

    foreach ($sParams as $key => $value)
    {
        return   $this->render('Bundle:Example:footerParams.html.twig',array('params' => $value));

    }

}
```

$value contains the number.

And this is the view:

```
{{ params }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And why not using a basic way to test is `code` is defined?

E.g:

```
{% if code is defined %}
    some code
{% endif %}
```

**Edit**

-Controller

```
/**
 * @Route("/footer_params/{code}", name="footer_params", defaults={"code"=null})
 *
 * @Template()
 */
 public function footerParamsAction($code)
 {
     $sParams = $this->getWebService('get_config_param', array('code' => $code));

    if (!isset($sParams)) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException();
    }

    return $this->render('Bundle:Example:footerParams.html.twig', [
        'params' => $sParams
    ]);
}
```

-View

You just have to work with params content:
E.g:

```
{% if params.phone %}
  phone : {{ params.phone }}
{% endif %}

/.../
```

Comment: The controller won't always return a value.I want to show a div only when there's a value.

Comment: Wow... And how is the value populate in the view?

Comment: the controller calls a web service and selects a specific phone number depending on the code (home,work,..) and I only want to show the numbers when I allow it.

Comment: from the backoffice if I put a number it should be shown or if I delete it, the hole div should be hided

Comment: So, the controller returns something to the view. May we have a glance to the controller?

Comment: When the controller returns an empty value I want to hide the div containing it.

Comment: I don't why I over complicated things.

Comment: :) Sometimes, answer is just under the eyes. ;)